# webpack, babel: es6 import vs. require for Fabric.js

Tags: webpack, fabricjs, babeljs

I am using webpack and babel in my development tool chain; when running the following code:

```
import * as fabric from 'fabric';

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
```

I get the following error:

```
_fabric2.default.Canvas is not a constructor
```

Whereas the same code works fine if I use `require('fabric');` instead of
`import`.

I tried different ways of calling `import` but none of them worked.

My linting tool complains of the undefined `fabric` variable, so I would like to have it properly defined. Surprisingly (for me), this code
doesn't work neither:

```
var fabric = require("fabric");
```

I get the following error in this case:

```
fabric.Canvas is not a constructor
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In my current setup using `fabric` from NPM, I use

`import {fabric} from 'fabric'`

to access to fabric global object.

Answer (score 4):

Looking into the source code you can figure out that `fabric` is made global by settin it on the window object.  So once you `require` or `import` you can start using fabric directly.  If you want it to be well defined you can get the definition from the window object.
 `var fabric = window['fabric']`

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/dist/fabric.js

Comment: So it means fabricjs doesn't comply with CommonJS or AMD module conventions ?

Comment: See kcjpop's answer, `import { fabric } from 'fabric';` works correctly

Answer (score 2):

Your `import` is incorrect. The following works fine:

```
import 'fabric'

let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(100,100,200)',
  selectionColor: 'blue',
  selectionLineWidth: 2
});
```