# How to install .d.ts for fabric

Tags: typescript, fabricjs

I am trying to install type definition for fabric (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fabric/) but I cannot figure out the right typings command.

At first I tried `typings install dt~fabric --global --save` and got the following error:

`$typings install dt~fabric --global --save
typings ERR! message Attempted to compile "fabric" as a global module, but it looks like an external module. You'll need to remove the global option to continue.`

Then I tried `typings install dt~fabric --save`, the typings command succeed but the `typings/modules/fabric/index.d.ts` file was differed with the original file `https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fabric/index.d.ts`. 
The `typings` command wraps the original content with `declare module 'fabric' {}`, which causes compiler error `Error:(9, 1) TS1316:Global module exports may only appear at top level.` at the statement `export as namespace fabric;` inside the .d.ts file.

typings version 2.1.0

Comment: did you try `npm install --save @types/fabric`?

Comment: there is no `@types/fabric`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is. Did you miss spelling it?

Comment: @AnyName Yes, you are correct......I found it now. But another problem arises, "Uncaught TypeError: fabric.Canvas is not a constructor",  like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984795/webpack-babel-es6-import-vs-require-for-fabric-js when using webpack, any ideas?

Comment: I solved it, I use a `<script>` tag and include `"fabric": "fabric"` in webpack `externals` ,thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save-dev @types/fabric
```

Will do the trick, [per the NPM docs.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/fabric)

You can see the [type definitions here.](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/fabric)

I used this when learning Fabric, and it was a **huge** help in understanding the API, due to IntelliSense.

Also, if you use `//@ts-check` at the top of any *.js file, it will also give you a rough estimate of what it believes is correct IntelliSense.

TypeScript 2.3 and later support a mode of type-checking and reporting errors in .js files with --checkJs. [The docs explain how it works.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files)